# Как сделать скрытый файл только для чтения программой python

Tags: python, файлы

Мне нужно сделать файл например с паролями. Надо, чтобы просто так файл открыть было нельзя, а программа на python чтобы видела всё содержимое. То есть существует файл, открыть его нельзя или при открытии ничего не будет понятно, а при запуске специальной программы, например, всё содержимое выводилось в консоль. Как это можно сделать, как такая техника называется и какой запрос лучше сделать для поиска информации по такой схеме?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шифровка через cryptography (кажется так пишется). Ключ ручками забивать. Пароли записываешь в строку, строку пропускаешь через шифровщик, и записываешь как байты в файл, но в конце ентер добавляешь. Обратно аналогично. Иначе - никак.